# Sending push notification apns w/o the use of a library (Java)

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications, jdk1.4

Can someone give me a sample code(Java) on pushing notification without using any apns libray(japns/java apns). I will be using jdk1.4(reason why I can't use japns/java apns). Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried compiling Java APNS yourself?  The source [is available here](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns), if the issue is just that you don't want to use a pre-built .jar file.  If the library uses features not available in Java 1.4, I would guess that you could just edit the code to use older constructs.